# Multi-select buttons in Selenium(Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

As part of automation testing, I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to access a multi-select button in my company website. This button is not design in the popular way and it causes me problems using Select library. Here is how it looks like:

```
<div class="select-options options-overflow drop-select-link" style="position: absolute; top: 373px; left: 492px; width: 53px;">
   <div class="drop-holder">
      <div class="drop-list" style="height: 100px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;">
         <ul>
            <li class="jcfcalc" rel="0">
               <a href="#">
               <span>USD</span>
               </a>
            </li>
            <li class="option-even jcfcalc" rel="1">
               <a href="#">
               <span>EUR</span>
               </a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What you see here is a multi-select button which displayed different kind of currencies. I want to be able to choose currencies in a wise way - something like Select library. However, Select library doesn't fit to my code.

Is there a library that I'm not aware of? or would I have to do it with XPaths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select()` couldn't be used with buttons. **Any** buttons! It could be used with `select`/`option` elements only!

In your case you can simply use link text to select required element (which is *link*, not the *button*) as

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("EUR")
driver.find_element_by_link_text("USD")
```